# Debugging a Go Process on a Container does not listen on the mapped port

Tags: docker, go, containers, remote-debugging, delve

I am using Goland IDE on MacOSX and I'm trying to debug an application running on the container.  I'm trying to attempt remote debugging, just that the container is on my local.
When I run the debugger on my IDE it does stop on the breakpoint but the one that it is debugging is the application on my **local** and **not** the one on the **container**.

For background, my application is supposed to listen on port 8000 and return "Hello, visitor!".
If I compile and run this file through a docker container, map my port 8000 and make a request through browser or through .http file, I do receive this response.
However, when I run it through Delve on the container, it does not respond through browser.

Also, once the container is up, when I start debugger on my IDE it does not debug the application on the container, as it complains about

```
2020/08/05 17:57:39 main.go:16: listen tcp :8000: bind: address already in use
```

I've tried following these 2 tutorials, both of which are mostly same, except for the version of their docker images that they use.

[Tutorial1](https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2018/04/30/debugging-containerized-go-applications/#commento-login-box-container)
[Tutorial2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2020/05/06/debugging-a-go-application-inside-a-docker-container/)

I have gone through all the comments on these 2 posts as well but haven't found anything that would solve my problem.

Here is my main.go

```
    package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)
func main() {
    // Set the flags for the logging package to give us the filename in the logs
    log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lshortfile)

    log.Println("starting server...")
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        _, _ = fmt.Fprintln(w, `Hello, visitor!`)
    })
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Compile stage
FROM golang AS build-env

# Build Delve
RUN git config --global http.sslVerify "false"
RUN git config --global http.proxy http://mycompanysproxy.com:80
RUN go get github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv

ADD . /dockerdev
WORKDIR /dockerdev
RUN go build -gcflags="all=-N -l" -o /server

# Final stage
FROM debian:buster
EXPOSE 8000 40000
WORKDIR /
COPY --from=build-env /go/bin/dlv /
COPY --from=build-env /server /

CMD ["/dlv", "--listen=:40000", "--headless=true", "--api-version=2", "--accept-multiclient", "exec", "/server"]
```

The container comes up successfully and the attached console's log says:

```
API server listening at: [::]:40000
```

However, it does not seem to be listening.
If I run

```
GET http://localhost:8000/
Accept: application/json
```

I expect it to stop on the **breakpoint** but it doesn't. Rather it complains:

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:8000 failed to respond
```

Am I missing something?
Is this the way to invoke debugger on a containerized app?

Some more information:
[image: configuration]

[image: configuration2]

[image: directory structure]

Comment: your debugger runs on your local(your computer/locahost). The container/docker-container, is running either the compiled binary of your application or running your go file(depending on your `docker build` and `docker run` commands). In either case you have to first debug your app on local and then run it in side your container.

Comment: It's running the compiled binary of my application. So do you mean to say that I first run the debugger in the IDE on main.go, once it stops at the breakpoint, I run the Dockerfile? Won't it complain about the same port already being used by the local app when it tries to bind the port?

Comment: if you try to run both debugger and application, it will complain, if you want to debug the application that will have to be done first and then the application can run(either in localhost or on docker). If you want to run application while debugging the original file you will need to remap the port to some other value (`:8080` or something like that). Yes if you try to bind both debugger and app to same port it will complain.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I was using the wrong debug configuration. Need to press debug button with remote debug (top right) showing in the configuration.
[image]